# How to remove some jobs from running in Laravel

Tags: laravel, queue, amazon-sqs, jobs

I have one worker currently running, utilizing SQS with Laravel Jobs.

Within my jobs, I invoke third-party services to perform actions on my products. Each job corresponds to a specific product (e.g., a job for Product A, another for Product B, etc.). In the event that the third-party service returns an error response for a particular product, I must remove all related jobs for that product from the queue.

For instance:

```
One Worker is active.
The number of available messages (jobs) is 500.
There are 40 jobs for Product A.
There are 100 jobs for Product B.
```

I require any job associated with Product B to trigger the third-party service that encountered an error and subsequently remove the other 99 jobs that are already in the queue for that product.

Is such functionality possible within the Laravel Queue?

Comment: You may want to use [Job Batching](https://laravel.com/docs/queues#job-batching). Batched Jobs return a `Illuminate\Bus\Batch` instance that can be managed while dispatched. Eg. you can add/remove jobs from the Batch, you can follow the progress and even cancel the entire Batch.